# Batch script for renaming and then moving files from 1 folder to another

Tags: batch-file, file-io, cmd

I have a file book.csv in folder `C:\sam`. I want to write .bat script renaming it first and then moving to `C:\samy`. Also the book.csv will be dynamic file name.

### Edit

I want a script so my file move from one folder to another and creates a new file, if any file already exists.

For example, I have a file test.csv in Downloads folder. When I run the below script if overrides the file if any file exists with the same name in downloads1 folder.

But I want, it shouldn't override the existing file but both the files should be there; maybe it changes the name.adds 1,2 behind.

```
move C:\user\Downloads\*.csv C:\user\downloads1\
```

Also I know using /-Y will ask me I needs to override. But I want to do this automatically.

```
move /-Y C:\user\Downloads\*.csv C:\user\downloads1\
```

Comment: Why renaming and then moving?Why not just moving?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@echo off
set /p new_name=set a new name   
 move /Y C:\sam\books.csv C:\samy\%new_name%.csv
```

or

```
@echo off 
 move /Y C:\sam\books.csv C:\samy\%%~1.csv
```

The first will ask the user for the new name.The second relies on command line argument e.g. `movescript.bat new_name`

**EDIT**
After the second request in the comments bellow it appears that the `ren` command should be used after all:

```
  @echo off
  set /p new_name=set a new name   
  move /Y C:\sam\books*.csv C:\samy\
  cd /D C:\samy\
  ren book_????_??_??.csv %new_name%_????_??_??.csv
```

or

```
    @echo off 
    move /Y C:\sam\books*.csv C:\samy\
    cd /D C:\samy\
    ren book_????_??_??.csv %%~1_????_??_??.csv
```

Comment: actually file name will be dynamic something like book_2013_10_16.csv. So i want to move then rename or rename then move...As in the command u suggested here the name will be static.I need this if i have dynamic file names.I want to rename it to static name book.csv only.Can you suggest

Comment: Thnaks for help mate...i am able to rename and move now..the problem is the books.csv will be coming dynamic something like book_2013_10_16.csv.Everytime it will be with different timestamp..C:\sam\books.csv will not work..can you help..mate...

Comment: Thanks mate..you saved my day..very helpful...exactly what i wanted.

Comment: @npocmaka - Do you have any ideas on the following item   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66770393/batch-script-rename-existing-file-else-copy-file-to-destination-folder)