# Batch Script - Rename Existing File Else COPY file to destination folder

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

I'm using BATCH Script (.bat) to copy files from Source folder to destination folder. If exists the file in the destination folder, I want to rename the file with Timestamp as suffix and Copy the new file. If NOT exists, I want to new file to copy itself.

This is my current code, which I found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/671270/how-to-optionally-copy-and-rename-a-file-in-windows)

```bat
@ECHO OFF

REM ### Needed so the variables will expand properly within the FOR DO loops ###
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM ### Set the source file(s) and call the "CopyIt" subroutine ###
SET Sourcefile=Arthematic.psf
CALL :CopyIt

REM ### End of the program.  Otherwise the subroutine will run again ###
GOTO END

REM ### The subroutine ###
:CopyIt
    REM ### Set the date and time to a variable called "DaTime" and remove offending ###
    REM ### characters (/ and :) that can't be used in a filename ###
    FOR /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%a in ("!date!") do SET DaTime=%%b-%%c-%%d
    FOR /f "tokens=1-3 delims=':'" %%e in ("!time!") do SET DaTime=!DaTime!_%%e-%%f-%%g

    REM ### Set a variable called "DestFile" to source filename minus ".psf" ###
    REM ### to be used to set the new destination file name + "DaTime" ###
    SET Destfile=!Sourcefile:.psf=!

    REM ### Check to see if the source filename exists in the destination directory ###
    DIR "C:\Program Files\Math\Core Simulate\M020\Arthematic\bin\!Sourcefile!" > NUL
    
    IF !ErrorLevel!==0 (
        REM ### If it does exist, set the loop count to 0 ###
        SET /a Count=0
        REM ### Have xcopy check to see if the source file is newer, but only report and not copy ###
        REM ### Thanks to selbie for suggesting the /L option ###
        FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=0" %%s in ('xcopy /Y /D /L "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Kollective\!Sourcefile!" "C:\Program Files\Math\Core Simulate\M020\Arthematic\bin\"') DO (
            REM ### Increment the loop count ###
            SET /a Count=!Count!+1
            REM ### Only pick up the first iteration.  If the files are different, it will be the full path and the filename ###
            If !Count!==1 SET Source=%%s
        )
        REM ### If the source is the same as the destination, then !Source! will = " File(s)".  Change it to NONE ###
        SET Source=!Source: File^(s^)=NONE!
        REM ### If it's not equal to NONE, copy the file and rename it to source file + date & time + .txt ###
        IF !Source! NEQ NONE COPY /Y "!Source!" "C:\Program Files\Math\Core Simulate\M020\Arthematic\bin\!Destfile!-!DaTime!.psf"
    ) ELSE (
        REM ### If it does not exist, copy the file without renaming it ###
        COPY /Y "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Kollective\!Sourcefile!" "C:\Program Files\Math\Core Simulate\M020\Arthematic\bin\"
    )
REM ### Exit the subroutine ###
EXIT /b

:END
pause
```

But, while executing the script from desktop, I'm getting the following error. Am I overlooking something?

[image]

Comment: [npocmaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388389/npocmaka) Do you have any ideas

Comment: I'll take a look.